# How can decision tree model in Spark (pyspark) be visualized?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, decision-tree, dtreeviz

I am trying to visualize decision tree structure in pyspark. But all the tools are for data. I could not find any for visualizing tree structure. Or is there a way I can visualize using the rules from `toDebugString`?

Comment: Could there be a way to port pyspark decision tree to scikit ad then use sklearn to generate graphviz dot file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have tried to do the following in order to create a visualization :

1. Parse Spark Decision Tree output to a `JSON` format.
2. Use the `JSON` file as an input to a `D3.js` visualization.

For more code you can refer to my prototype at GitHub [here](https://github.com/hechemeljed/Decision-Tree-Visualization-Spark).

Answer (score 1):

I'm also a bigdata/ml engineer and I had many time the need to visualize the decision trees from Spark.

We've just released [dtreeviz](https://github.com/parrt/dtreeviz) 1.1 , which includes support for Spark.
You can now visualize the tree structure, leaf information, prediction path and more. Just check this [notebook](https://github.com/parrt/dtreeviz/blob/master/notebooks/dtreeviz_spark_visualisations.ipynb) for more examples.

[image]
[image]